# In a competitive equilibrium, can price of a commodity ever be zero?

Tags: microeconomics, competitive-equilibrium

I don't think they can be, but I'm not very sure. Are their special cases where the equilibrium is competitive even when prices are zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the assumptions you make.

If you assume that preferences are [locally insatiable](https://books.google.hu/books?id=8tW9KAnkx04C&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=locally%20insatiable&source=bl&ots=zhsgeinWKc&sig=W0NxaFP4Anin1vNpXIwSu2oslgI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwA2oVChMIjJbuyfyOxgIV4RTbCh3WbQAS#v=onepage&q=locally%20insatiable&f=false) then no.

Without this assumption, it is easy to construct counterexamples. 
 Consider an economy with two consumers ($A,B$) and two goods ($x,y$). Both consumers have preferences represented by their utility function
$$
U_i(x_i,y_i) = \min(x_i,1) + y_i.
$$ 
If the initial endowments are such that the total supply of $x$ is larger than 2 then the equilibrium price of $x$ is 0. (The numeraire is the good $y$.)